# Get product out of digits in a string

Tags: string, haskell, type-conversion, product

For instance if input is "12345" I want the outcome to be 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 = 120.
I wrote the following:

```
import Data.Char    

stringProduct :: Int -> [Char] -> Int
stringProduct p [] = p
stringProduct p (n:ns) = stringProduct np ns
        where np = p * (digitToInt n)

main =
    print $ stringProduct 1 "12345"
```

Why do I get `8.hs:3:1: Parse error in pattern: stringProduct`?
UPDATE: solved this first problem.

But what if the outcome is an Integer?

Comment: Mind that read expects a `String` but you feed it `n`, a `Char`.

Comment: also you want `(n:ns)`

Answer (score 4):

The first problem is that you need to put brackets around your `n:ns` pattern, otherwise Haskell interprets it as `stringProduct p n : ns`:

```
stringProduct :: Integer -> [Char] -> Integer
stringProduct p [] = p
stringProduct p (n:ns) = stringProduct np ns
        where np = p * (digitToInt n)
```

But now the compiler will complain about the types:

```
product.hs:4:30:
    Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[Char]’
    Expected type: String
      Actual type: Char
    In the first argument of ‘read’, namely ‘n’
    In the second argument of ‘(*)’, namely ‘(read n)’
```

You can fix this by `read`ing `[n]` instead of `n` (converting it to a one-character string):

```
stringProduct :: Integer -> [Char] -> Integer
stringProduct p [] = p
stringProduct p (n:ns) = stringProduct np ns
        where np = p * (read [n])
```

Now:

```
*Main> main
120
```

---

To answer your second question an `Int` is - as [@ThomasM.DuBuisson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36917888/get-product-out-of-digits-in-a-string/36918006#comment61401476_36918006) pointed out - at least 30 bits (the range of -2<sup>29</sup> up to 2<sup>29</sup>-1), but has a fixed precision (for instance 64 bits). An `Integer` however has an arbitrary precision: as long as your machines has enough free memory (and the operating system is willing to share it), it will use that memory to store the entire value of the integer. As a result there is no theoretical maximum value for an `Integer` (truth is of course that if your machine has - swap space included - for instance a memory of 8 GiB, the maximum value will be something like 2<sup>2<sup>33</sup></sup>, which is not infinite, although it will suffice for most practical applications).

Take for instance two short versions of your program:

```
stringProductInteger :: String -> Integer
stringProductInteger = product . map (read . (:[]))

stringProductInt :: String -> Int
stringProductInt = product . map (read . (:[]))
```

Now if we do the experiment:

```
*Main> stringProductInt "123456789123456781234567213456723456712345678"
3092908213020917760
*Main> stringProductInteger "123456789123456781234567213456723456712345678"
75525861717854650368000000
```

The `Int` *overflowed* at 64 bits, thus the result is the result with `Integer` but with wraparounds. For example:

```
*Main> (2^33) :: Int
8589934592
*Main> (2^64) :: Int
0
*Main> (2^64) :: Integer
18446744073709551616
*Main> (2^63) :: Integer
9223372036854775808
*Main> (2^63) :: Int
-9223372036854775808
```

Comment: `an int is at least 32 bits`  No, actually. In current versions of GHC perhaps, but the Haskell language only promises 29 bits: "Haskell guarantees only that Int covers at least the range [−229,229 − 1] (Section 6.4)"

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: If it covers -2^29 up to 2^29-1, it contains at least 30 bits I think. Nevertheless well spotted ;).

Answer (score 3):

As I was reminded by @epsilonhalbe, this is far better:

```
stringProduct = product . map digitToInt
```

---

You can simplify this with a few higher-order functions:

```
stringProduct :: String -> Integer
stringProduct s = product $ map read (map (:[]) s)
```

Breaking it down...

```
> map (:[]) "123"
["1", "2", "3"]
> map read ["1", "2", "3"] :: [Integer]
[1,2,3]
> product [1,2,3]
6
```

Comment: or `product . map digitToInt`

Comment: For some reason, I was thinking `digitToInt` was not standard Haskell, but something written by the OP.

Comment: IIRC it is only a `import Data.Char (digitToInt)` away

Comment: Although this is a correct answer (take another +1), I think for educational purposes, one should be careful introducing too much functions at once (especially higher order). You can probably further reduce it to `stringProduct = product . map (read . (:[]))` as well :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Agreed. I did resist the urge to define `stringProduct` in point-free style :)